# SlideToggle imperfections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My slideToggle is a little jumpy at the bottom of the slide transition. Could that be because there is a button there or something. Any way to make it smoother. Tried using easing but not very successful. Any suggestions

click on video setup to see for yourself
[The site](https://posnation.com/pos_support)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.drop').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down').slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `li.drop_down` a fixed width. This should clear it up. I don't remember the exact reason for this, but I just tested it on your site, and it works.

Right now the computed width is `217px` so try that.

```
.drop_down {
    width: 217px;
}
```

**EDIT:** Looks like you have a `.drop_down2` and a `.drop_down3` as well (maybe more). You would need to do the same for those. I'd suggest assigning a common class for each.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the height of each item before animating it, and then re-apply that height to the element just before starting the hiding animation.

Here's an article I wrote how with an example of doing this:
http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/jquery-smooth-animation

Comment: Reapplying the height over & over seems to be unnecessary. In my own code, I was able to just set the height of each element-to-be-toggled to its computed height. Something like `$('dd').each(function(i) { this.style.height = $(this).height(); });` before hiding & then applying the slideToggle.

Comment: Ah, I see.  BTW, what version of jQuery did you test with?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed width didn't work for me, but what did was **adding a clearfix class** to the animated element, since I had some floated elements inside.